# Vue router link working only after refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am updating navigation links based on current user login status. So if user is not logged in then show register and login links. if user is logged in then show dashboard and logout links. When I log in using login form then the links change in the navigation bar but when I click on "logout" link, it doesn't work. Means it simply don't do anything when I click logout. Not even an error on console.

Now if I refresh the page and then click on "Logout" then it works and logs out the user properly.

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Below is the code :

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

    <router-link tag="li" active-class="active"
        :to="{ name: 'login' }"
        v-if="!this.$store.getters.isAuthenticated">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Login</a>
    </router-link>

    <router-link tag="li" active-class="active"
        :to="{ name: 'register' }"
        v-if="!this.$store.getters.isAuthenticated">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Register</a>
    </router-link>

    <router-link tag="li" active-class="active"
        :to="{ name: 'dashboard' }"
        v-if="this.$store.getters.isAuthenticated">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Dashboard</a>
    </router-link>

    <router-link tag="li" active-class="active"
        :to="{ name: 'logout' }"
        v-if="this.$store.getters.isAuthenticated">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Logout</a>
    </router-link>

</ul>
```

Below is the router.js code

```
export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            component: () => import('./views/Home.vue'),
        },
        {
            path: '/company/login',
            name: 'login',
            component: () => import('./views/Company/Login.vue'),
            meta: {
                forVisitor: true
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/company/register',
            name: 'register',
            component: () => import('./views/Company/Register.vue'),
            meta: {
                forVisitor: true
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/company/logout',
            name: 'logout',
            component: () => import('./views/Company/Logout.vue')
        },
        {
            path: '/dashboard',
            name: 'dashboard',
            component: () => import('./views/Company/Dashboard.vue'),
            meta: {
                forAuth: true
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

And here is the code from main.js file

```
// navigation guard
router.beforeEach(
    (to, from, next) => {
        if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.forVisitor)){
            if(store.getters.isAuthenticated){
                next({
                    name: "dashboard"
                })
            } else next()
        }
        else if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.forAuth)){
            if(! store.getters.isAuthenticated){
                next({
                    name: "login"
                })
            } else next()
        }
        else {
            next()
        }
    }
)

new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Show your router code, please.

Comment: Did you find the url changed ?

Comment: @Styx just updated the question with full code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this the main problem is tag="li"

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
 <li><router-link active-class="active"
        :to="{ name: 'login' }"
        v-if="!this.$store.getters.isAuthenticated">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Login</a>
    </router-link></li>

 <li><router-link  active-class="active"
        :to="{ name: 'register' }"
        v-if="!this.$store.getters.isAuthenticated">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Register</a>
    </router-link></li>


    <li><router-link  active-class="active"
        :to="{ name: 'dashboard' }"
        v-if="this.$store.getters.isAuthenticated">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Dashboard</a>
    </router-link></li>

   <li> <router-link active-class="active"
        :to="{ name: 'logout' }"
        v-if="this.$store.getters.isAuthenticated">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Logout</a>
    </router-link></li>

</ul>
```

Note: no need for this `<a href="#" class="nav-link">Logout</a>` you can samply do like

```
<li> <router-link active-class="active"
            :to="{ name: 'logout' }"
            v-if="this.$store.getters.isAuthenticated">

        </router-link>Logout</li>
```